# php show event if server date/time is between two time values

Tags: php, date, time

I'm not trying to do this with MySQL as I see is common. I am merely trying to create a PHP Script that will display information like this using the servers time and date as a reference:

```
Monday 2:30am to Tuesday 2:29am - Content A
Tuesday 2:30am to Wednesday 2:29am - Content B
Wednesday 2:30am to Thursday 2:29am - Content C
and so on....
```

Until every day of the week in covered, for some reason I can't seem to nail this and there doesn't seem to be and examples to build from. Is this for some reason not possible?

---

Edit

---

I've used the following code and it's proving to not be as reliable as it should be.

```
function isInTimeWindow($dayName, $startHour, $startMinute, $endHour, $endMinute) 
{ 
   $dayName = ucfirst($dayName); 
   list($dayNow, $timeNow) = explode('|', date('l|Hi')); 
   return ( 
      ucfirst($dayName) == $dayNow and 
      $timeNow >= sprintf('%02d%02d', $startHour, $startMinute) and 
      $timeNow <= sprintf('%02d%02d', $endHour, $endMinute) 
   ); 
} 
// tuesdays during day 
if(isInTimeWindow('tuesday', 02, 30, 23, 00)) { 
?>
CONTENT
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: .. and what you tried so far?

Comment: PHP is a Turing-complete language, so unless you hit a practical limit on something everything is possible. Do you have problems with something *specific*?

Answer (score 0):

So long as you're happy using the server's time rather than the client's time this can be done using the [getdate()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php) function.

For example, if you just wanted to do it based on day of the week:

```
<?php

$now = getdate();

switch($now['wday']) {
case 0:
?>
Content A
<?
break;
etc.
```

Edit: here is how to do it in more detail:

getdate() provides you with information about the hour and minute parts too.

You could have a function like :

```
// Get's the 0-indexed day of the week offset so each "day" starts and 2:30am
function get_offset_day() {
    $now = getdate();
    if ($now['hours']*60 + $now['minutes'] < 150) { // less 2h 30m after midnight => still "yesterday"
        $answer = $now['wday']-1;
    }
    else {
        $answer = $now['wday'];
    } 
    if ($answer < 0) return 6;
    return $answer;
}
```

Comment: Yes but time plays an important role in this script. The script has to show the content until 2:29am the next morning, then at 2:30am, switch to the current day of the week.

Comment: getdate() provides you with information about the hour and minute parts too. 

See edited for a function which will get you an offset day of the week which you can use to choose which content to display using a switch.

Answer (score 0):

you could use date(l) [php manual date() function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php) function to get the actual weekday in words (Monday, Tuesday, ... ) so you can check the weekday.

Use mktime function [php manual mktime() function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mktime.php) to convert your times ( Monday, 2:30am for example ) into timestamps and check if it is between current time by using time function [php manual time() function](http://php.net/manual/de/function.time.php)

EDIT: Here's an example:

```
$today_start = mktime(2, 30, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$today_end = mktime(2, 29, 0, date('m'), (date('d') + 1), date('Y'));


if ( $today_start < time() && $today_end > time() )
    // code
```

mktime works like this: mktime( hour, minutes, seconds, month, day, year )

Comment: can you post an example of what you mean? i am not familiar with this method.

Comment: Hey, I hope so: 

Use date(l) ( in a switch maybe ) to get the actual weekday, i guess that should be obvious. 

With:

$today_start = mktime(2, 30, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
$today_end = mktime(2, 29, 0, date('m'), (date('d') + 1), date('Y'));

you always get the timestamp of TODAY at 2:30am. Now you can check if $today_start < time() AND $today_end > time().

Comment: Ok I get that, but the day of the week is really what's important since there is going to be different content to display 7 days a week. I don't see where I would fit that into this script. (Thank you so far btw)

Comment: what I meant to say is every day is going to have different content, but the content repeats every week.